# Highlight a specific DIV

Tags: jquery, html, highlight

I'm trying to 'hightlight' a specific div.

Here is my html code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <link href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
        <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
        <style type="text/css">div { margin: 0px; width: 300px; height: 80px; background: #FFF; border: 1px solid black; position: relative; }</style>
        <script>
            $(document).ready(function() {
                $("a").click(function () {
                    $("div").effect("highlight", {color:"#FF0000"}, 3000);
                });
            });
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <a href="#id_1"><b>id_1</b></a>
        <br/>
        <a href="#id_2"><b>id_2</b></a>

        <br/><br/><br/><br/>
        <div id="id_1"><h2>id_1 - <a class="altlink" href="#top" name="id_1" id="id_1">Top</a></h2></div>
        <div id="id_2"><h2>id_2 - <a class="altlink" href="#top" name="id_2" id="id_2">Top</a></h2></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

When I click on the `a` element with the href `#id_1`, how can I make it highlight the `<div id="id_1">` element?

Thanks !

Comment: By the way, you shouldn't have the same id used on several elements of the DOM

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
$('a[href^="#id"]').on('click', function() {
    var sHref = this.href.split('/');
    $(sHref[sHref.length - 1]).effect("highlight", {
        color: "#FF0000"
    }, 3000);
});
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/maniator/4PgC6/

---

**Side note**: If using jQuery < 1.7 then do:

```
$('a[href^="#id"]').click(function() {
    var sHref = this.href.split('/');
    $(sHref[sHref.length - 1]).effect("highlight", {
        color: "#FF0000"
    }, 3000);
});
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/maniator/4PgC6/9/

Comment: @mblase75 What are you talking about? Neither the question nor this answer uses jQuery UI anywhere.

Comment: @JamWaffles Isn't that where the '.effect' method comes from?

Comment: only use this if you know you will be using jQuery 1.7+ otherwise use `$('a[href=^"#id"]').click(function(){....`

Comment: @mblase75 I do apologise; I didn't see that. I even used `.effect()` in my own answer!

Comment: @JamWaffles it does. it uses the `effect`. I changed my answer to reflect it.

Comment: @JohnStrave **no problem ^_^**, don't forget to accept an answer when you can :-)

Comment: @JohnStrave Try `alert(this.href);` to see what it looks like. and the same with `alert(sHref);`

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$('a').click(function() {
    var selector = $(this).attr('href');

    // Highlight div with whatever CSS you like
    $(selector).effect("highlight", {color:"#FF0000"}, 3000);
}
```

This uses the `href` attribute of the link as the selector for the `.effect()` line.

Answer (score 0):

you need to use here like this :

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("a").click(function () {
                    $(this).parent().parent().effect("highlight", {color:"#FF0000"}, 3000);
                });
            });
```

EDIT : fixed the mistake, put the second .parent() call

Comment: Why would you highlight the parent?

Comment: @Neal because parent is the div to be highlighted

Answer (score 0):

> $(document).ready(function() {  $("a#id_1").click(function () {
>   $("div#id_1").effect("highlight", {color:"#FF0000"}, 3000);    return
>   false;  });  $("a#id_2").click(function () {
>   $("div#id_2").effect("highlight", {color:"#0000FF"}, 3000);    return
>   false;               }); });
>
> and the HTML would have an "A" tag which is
>   
>   [code]

a href="#" id="id1"

a href="#" id="id2"